# Would this question about printing a webpage be on-topic on Super User?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, on-topic

I'm trying to print a Medium post:

https://medium.com/@keeper6928/how-to-unit-test-machine-learning-code-57cf6fd81765

but no matter what I do, the code chunks get cropped. In the actual question, of course, I would add much more details, such as my enviroment, some pictures of the desired output and actual output, etc. [Super User help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) states that questions about "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress" are off-topic. However, I'm not asking about Medium features: I just want to understand why I can't print the darn page. Would this be on-topic?

Comment: I would say it is on topic as it is about printing physical copies, not the service itself. But I would defer to someone with more experience.

Comment: That would be on topic.

Comment: The facebook, twitter and wordpress question 'ban' is actually really unclear what it means. Now you're question has highlighted this, I'm wondering myself!

Comment: If its about using all those - its off topic. If its vaguely about doing something with it about something else, and that something else is on topic, it is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Its a web *browser*, *os* and *printer* question - so I'd say yes, and with examples (especially if it does the same on a PDF print - so you can screenshot examples), its on topic.

Comment: I can repro with a pdf print.

Comment: I see no issues then

Comment: Cool, I'll prepare the screenshots and post the question, then. Thanks!

Comment: Keep the question contained to the issue you face.  Don't ask for other services you can use, or how to modify the settings on the website in question, just keep it to the browser/os/printer.